# background service for ble scan using cordova plugin

Tags: android, ios, cordova, bluetooth-lowenergy, cordova-plugins

I have used https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle to scan the ble devices and able to extract required info. However, I need this to run this scan in the background for scanning only( as a service).
I read through several queries answered in this forum,([Cordova: Scan for iBeacons / BLE in background mode (iOS and Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32697145/cordova-scan-for-ibeacons-ble-in-background-mode-ios-and-android) & [cordova plugins bluetooth background service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782954/cordova-plugins-bluetooth-background-service))
[Android BLE Passive scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994776/android-ble-passive-scan)
but they are more towards android native and IOS specific.

SO can the scan for BLE devices can be achieved as a background service using a plugin in?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

I'm using

```
cordova-plugin-background-mode
```

and

```
cordova-plugin-ble-central
```

With those two plugins, yes, I'm scanning and connecting and read / write from the background.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Appreciate if you could guide how could you acheive this. For me , the scanning stops as soon as it finds the first device.

Comment: When I try to use this plugin getting error:plugin de.appplant.cordova.plugin.backgroundmode@0.6.4 not found locally. note plugin registry was disabled by --noregistry. any inputs?

Answer (score 0):

I faced some issues on Android when scanning, using the start Scan and Stop scan method worked. Performance on iOS was superior.

I was facing performance issues on Android while iOS was working fine when using

```
ble.scan(services, seconds, success, failure);
```

I resolved it by switching to

```
ble.startScan(services, success, failure);
```

And then calling the stop scan once the matched device is found

```
ble.stopScan(success, failure);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Here is the plug-in I used https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central